# How to move a SharePoint project from development server to Production Server

Tags: list, web-part, production

I developed a SharePoint List and corresponding 'NewForm' Visual Web Part using Visual Studio 2013.

The whole solution is very well on our development environment.

Now, we are in need of moving this SharePoint List and corresponding Web Part to Production environment. I have no idea how we can achieve this.

I don't want to develop whole project again on production environment.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you deploy it to your development environment? Directly with Visual Studio? You can easily deploy your WSP package to production and activate it, it will give you your list + web part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to move SharePoint solutions is using .wsp file which is created as you deploy any solution just copy from development, paste in production and then add and deploy solution there by power shell.
To move list use export functionality in central admin of development and then import the .cmp file in production.

done!

Comment: If the list is part of the WSP package it will be created when the feature is activated, no need to mode it.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to moving/copying/migrating lists and other elements from one environment to another i have  good experiences of using the Product ShareGate. In the gui you select Source and Target and then you can map additional properties and thereafter migrate the elements (and/or content etc.). I am not sure of if it will be able to migrate your customized web part but it can be worth a try to download the 15 days free trial and see if it does it  for you. Below you see an example of how the gui looks.
[image: Example of GUI]